# how do I get a list of SQL Servers System procs

Tags: sql-server

I know how to use sys.objects or sys.procedures to get a list of regular procs. How do I get a list of the system stored procedures in master that start with 'sp_'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sys.all_objects`:

```sql
USE master; --I am assuming you haven't created any User objects in master.
GO

SELECT *
FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE [type] = 'P';
```

If you *do* have user objects in `master` (I advise against this), add the following to the `WHERE`:

```sql
  AND schema_id = 4 --sys
  AND is_ms_shipped = 1 --Just in case
```

Comment: Yes. You beat me. I just found out by using SQL Server Profiler and then observing the queries that are sent by SQL Server Management Studio when expanding nodes in its Object Explorer. :)

Answer (score -1):

I have to start using sysobjects (much better than sys.objects.)

This will do it too (in master):

```
select * from dbo.sysobjects where type ='P'
```

Comment: Don't use these old `dbo.sys{name}` objects; they are for compatibility with SQL Server **2000** databases. Use the `sys` schema objects. See [sys.sysobjects (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). *"much better than sys.objects."* This statement is wrong. They are not "better", they are worse as the old objects don't supply all the details about objects as SQL Server has changed **a lot** over the last 21 years.

Comment: *"**Important:** This SQL Server 2000 system table is included as a view for backward compatibility. We recommend that you use the current SQL Server system views instead. To find the equivalent system view or views, see [Mapping System Tables to System Views (Transact-SQL)](/learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql). This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature."*

Comment: Your right. Thats why my first shot at doing stuff is going against sys.objects. But in this case....